# I want to clear my output screen in Java using NetBeans IDE 6.9.1

Tags: java, output, netbeans-6.9

### **My entire code can be found at the link below, I'm linking it for the sake of a shorter post**

http://pastebin.com/6kw8cx3b

I want to clear the Output screen, I'm to make the program simulate a user pressing ctrl+L, which in NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 (which I'm using) clears my output window.  However, I'm getting errors with my code.

```
public static void clearme()
{
    try
    {
        botthing pressbot = new botthing();
        pressbot.keyPress(17); // Holds CTRL key.
        pressbot.keyPress(76); // Holds L key.
        pressbot.keyRelease(17); // Releases CTRL key.
        pressbot.keyRelease(76); // Releases L key.
    }
    catch (AWTException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

My errors were...

Cannot find symbol
  symbol: class botthing

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AWTException

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Logger

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LoginPage

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Level

**HOWEVER!**  After adding these import statements

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

my errors are...

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class botthing
  location: class program2

exception java.awt.AWTException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LoginPage
  location: class program2

I'm not sure what those mean, but I think the java.awt error could be related to my main(), which is 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

All I want to do is clear my output screen.  I've also tried

```
for(int x=0;x<999;x++)
{
    System.out.print("\b\b\b\b\b");
}
```

and

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

but both to no avail.

If the code I've been trying can't be easily fixed, or if someone knows an easier way, I'd love to know.  To clarify, all I want to do is clear my Output window after multiple System.out.println's and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

botthing is not something defined in the JDK, and if it is a class that you defined, your compiler is not finding it.

Try using:

```
try {
    Robot pressbot = new Robot();
    pressbot.keyPress(17); // Holds CTRL key.
    pressbot.keyPress(76); // Holds L key.
    pressbot.keyRelease(17); // Releases CTRL key.
    pressbot.keyRelease(76); // Releases L key.
} catch (AWTException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: I pasted in that code, but my errors are: 
 | exception java.awt.AWTException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement | cannot find symbol symbol:   class Robots location: class program2 | cannot find symbol symbol:   class LoginPage location: class program2 |

Comment: @BrandonDurst My mistake, just a typo, it is **Robot** and not Robots, however this error means you didn't import your classes, to import Robot class put `import java.awt.Robot;` after the package declaration if you have one, for other classes i don't know what you have to import, as they are not java pre-defined classes, you have to look how the package that contains your classes is named and import them

Comment: I'm still getting the error "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LoginPage
  location: class program2"
also, it clears my 'table heading lines'

Comment: Nevermind, apparently it was a timing issue.  I inserted "for(int crap=0;crap<99999;crap++){}" after the clearme() statement and it fixed it.